# IIS Express, SQL Express as production server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

Can Microsoft's IIS Express and SQL Express servers be implemented for a small web application in production environment?

What is the limitation of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQL Express

Yes. This – small server – is its target use case.

> IIS Express

Given it requires an interactive user session: no. And that's assuming no licence issues.

But why would you want to use IIS Express? On *every* machine you can run IIS Express you have IIS available.

Comment: I have an intranet application that need to be used by 5 or less user. SO I dont want to buy any license. thats why.

Comment: @BlueBird: Licence for what? IIS is included in all Windows editions.

Comment: So, don't we need seperat license for that? That's great!

Answer (score 0):

You should just ensure that iis has been enabled on the web server you're planning to use.  It's there for sure just might not be activated.  No additional license is necessary.

Comment: how much capacity can a SQL Express database carry?

Comment: 10Gb total space. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx